# Unable to migrate Django app with South on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've installed South on my existing Django app. This Django app is on Heroku as well.

Without making any changes to the models, I've done the following commands locally:

- `manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial`
- `manage.py migrate --fake`

Then I attempted to push heroku master, and migrate there. But I receive the following:

```
Running migrations for app_name:
- Nothing to migrate.
  - Loading initial data for notecards.
No fixtures found
```

I get the same message if I try to fake the Heroku migrate.

I figured, this may be ok since technically there is nothing to migrate as the db stays the same.

So I made a small change to one of the models and did the following:

- `manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto`
- `manage.py migrate`

I then pushed to Heroku and attempted to migrate there, and I still receive the following:

```
Running migrations for app_name:
- Nothing to migrate.
  - Loading initial data for notecards.
No fixtures found
```

Any help with what I'm doing wrong would be great. THanks.

Comment: My migrations folders now has two entries 0001 (which was the init) and 0002. However, the issue occurred before I made the 2nd migration.

Comment: Are you sure you've committed the new migration? Check the migrations folder on Heroku and ensure that there actually are not already ran migrations there.

Comment: That put me on the right track. I needed to recursively remove previous migrations, and then start with the new migrations. THanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this issue, and for my own reference. Thanks to Chris Pratt for putting me on the right track.

This was resolved by:

Locally:

recursively removing any old migrations `git rm -r migrations`

flushing old database (this removes all data, but for me this wasnt an issue) `manage.py flush`

delete migrations folder in app folder

run initial schemamigration `manage.py schemamigration --initial`

run fake migrate `manage.py migrate --fake`

push heroku master

On Heroku:

migrate `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name`

Then, locally, you can run migrate --auto, push to heroku, and run migrate app_name

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work, besides being almost unintelligible.

Comment: What part of the answer do you not understand? It's essentially just recursively removing the migrations, then creating a new migration. It works, at least at the time of writing, but it removes the migrations completely - maybe that's not what you're looking for. Perhaps you'd be better off creating your own question and having it answered.

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but did you ever find a way to handle this without nuking your database?  Just curious, since I have this same issue and tho I only nuke the local db, which is "technically" no big deal, it's just a hassle.

Comment: Sorry, my project was still in development so it wasn't an issue to remove the migrations completely.